# How to stop .dirs files from resetting?

Tags: nautilus, document

I have a dual boot set up with Windows and Ubuntu. I have 3 partitions, 1 for Windows, 1 for Ubuntu and 1 for documents. I have linked the document folders on the docs partition to the user doc folders on windows, but when I change the file: `/home/bob/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, to link them to Ubuntu, but it changes back on restart!

This is what I change the file to:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Desktop/Ubuntu"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Dowloads/Downloads-U"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/media/bob/Documents/Videos"
```

This works but changes the values I change to `$HOME/` when I restart.

Please help. I'm new to Linux.

UPDATE:

@Helio , You're right, the partition is mounting on boot up, I went back and check the tutorial I followed to set up the dual boot. The tutorial is outdated so I couldn’t follow the steps. It tell me to

"head to Software Sources in the System->Administration menu. From there go to Applications, then the Ubuntu Software Center at the bottom. Under the "Ubuntu Software" and "Updates" sections, add a check to the un-checked sources, like Restricted, Multiverse, Proposed, and Backports. Hit "Close," and agree to Reload your software sources."

and then to download ntfs configuration tool, mount the partition and give it read/write access, the promgram has changed I doesn’t give me an option to mount. I know I can mount by right clicking the partition and selecting mount, but I don’t think that mounts it before boot each time.

UPADATE:   `cat /etc/fstab` outputs:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

    #Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
    UUID=ab83fe58-ce76-4818-a3d3-ee2e7b9dab46   /   ext4 errors=remount-ro  0   1
    #Entry for /dev/sdb3 :
    UUID=3E71C95C6B47A62D   /media/Documents    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_AU.UTF-8 0   0
```

Comment: Can you put the reseted file?

Comment: Not at the monment I'm on an Ipad but it's the same except instead of the paths I changed (the ones starting with`/media`) is says `$HOME/`.

Comment: Whats xdg, sorry, I'm new to linux.

Comment: Maybe nautilus is checking if the folder exists before the volume is mounted and then overwrites the configuration file. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1324358

Comment: Sorry, I meant `xdg-user-dirs-update` that is the program that allows to update this conf. file. However I was wrong, I seen in the launchpad bug edited above that is Nautilus which screws up the file.

Comment: Do you know a way to fix this?

Comment: Did the data partiton mount at boot? Is listed in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Sorry I can't find out right now but I know the partition table is msdos, does that help? Ubuntu is on the second partition and the document partition is last(3rd).

Comment: No, it does not help. However, when you can reach your computer, please update the question with the output of the command `cat /etc/fstab`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help @Helio, you were right about the program not being able to access the partition before it changed the file. However I don’t think it was a problem with not mounting before the program ran, I used NTFS Configuration tools to change the read/write settings and that fixed it.

To people having the same problem: Install NTFS Configuration tools(available in Ubuntu software centre) and change the setting of the partition to allow read write access.